# How to use regex character class extensions in R?

Tags: r, regex

This simple regular expression for matching each single digit

```
gregexpr('[[:digit:]]', 'a1b2c3')
```

returns what I expect:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 4 6
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

But the R documentation suggests a more compact syntax:

> Symbols \d, \s, \D and \S denote the digit and space classes and their
>   negations (these are all extensions).

So I tried

```
gregexpr('[\d]', 'a1b2c3')
```

but this returns an error:

```
Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'[\d"
```

How is this "extension" used?

Comment: Try `gregexpr('\\d', 'a1b2c3')`.

Comment: @Lamia Thanks- that did the trick.  Would you like to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
gregexpr('[[:digit:]]', 'a1b2c3')
```

is

```
gregexpr('\\d', 'a1b2c3')
```

You need to precede the regex character class by a double backslash (`\\`).